# HAProxy with really dynamic backend

Tags: ssl, haproxy, sni

I was wondering if it was possible to build something like this:

```
frontend  main
    bind *:443
    mode tcp
    tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
    tcp-request content accept if { req.ssl_hello_type 1 }
    tcp-request content reject
    use_backend be
backend be
    mode tcp
    server proxied %[req.ssl_sni]:443
```

I know this does not work but maybe someone can shed some light on how to do that.

I want to automatically proxy the connections to my main boxes without having to set up hundreds of backend entries manually. These also vary every second day.

My goal is to archive HTTPS proxying without interception.